# Historical notes on the Jordan-Hölder program

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, group-cohomology, simple-groups

I'm looking for any material (books, articles..) documenting the historical process of the formulation, partial work and/or the actual stage of the Jordan-Hölder program.

I'm not sure if there is any ambiguity in defining the program, but I mean the program that had as its objectives:

1. Classifying all finite simple groups
2. Classifying all the possible ways to put up simple groups together (The actual 'Extension Problem')

I'm currently studying the elementary topics which build up to the extension problem and I'm looking for the context of what I'm studying. Most of my material on math history (even those on algebra history) don't cover this topic. Actually, those who cover group theory focus mostly on Galois theory and some combinatorics.

I have a feeling this is a very specific topic to document, and even though Math Exchange is a English board, for broadening sake foreing language material is also welcome (I would be especially grateful for material in English or French, which I can easily read, though if none is avaible I would gladly take some recess time to try and read other languages, math history and the program itself interest me much)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A article by the AMS appears to cover the first topic. I haven't read it yet, tho. A quick word search also revealed numerous references to group extensions. http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2001-38-03/S0273-0979-01-00909-0/S0273-0979-01-00909-0.pdf